# How can I change file icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

How can I change file icons in Windows 7?

I don't want to use any tools for this purpose - I've tried some registry hacks but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The registry keys are under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Your program will need Administrator permissions to be able to modify them.

Every file type registered will have an entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, for example `.suo`. The value of this key will be a more verbose file type, in my example `VisualStudio.Launcher.suo`. Go to that key and you'll find another key underneath it, `DefaultIcon`. The value of this key will be the name of the file containing the icon and an index to the proper icon within the file.